# Create summary.newclass that prints summary.dynlm

Tags: r, methods

**Problem:** I would like to build on `summary.dynlm` from Achim Zeileis' dynlm package. I have been able to do the following with `summary.lm` but not with `summary.dynlm`.

I am slowly learning the advanced programming aspects of R and am transitioning my own package into one that uses S3 methods for cleaner function outputs. In this case I would like to have my methods run existing methods, as I am only making small additions.

For simplicity and reproducibility see the code below:

```
library(dynlm)
mod <- dynlm(interest ~ loggnp, M1Germany)
class(mod) <- c("newclass","dynlm","lm")

summary.newclass <- function(x, ...){
  cat(" some new stuff here")
  "if"(TRUE, cat("\n\tmaybe more here\n"), cat("\n\t oo fancy new stuff\n"))
  print(summary.lm(x)) # Works with lm
  #print(summary.dynlm(x)) # What I want to run instead
}
summary(mod)
```

When I comment out `print(summary.lm(x))`, uncomment `print(summary.dynlm(x))` and run, I receive the following error:

```
 Error in print(summary.dynlm(x)) : 
  could not find function "summary.dynlm"
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling `summary.dynlm` directly, I think the proper way is to dispatch to `NextMethod()`.

Your code becomes

```
library(dynlm)
mod <- dynlm(interest ~ loggnp, M1Germany)
class(mod) <- c("newclass","dynlm","lm")

summary.newclass <- function(x, ...){
  cat(" some new stuff here")
  print(NextMethod())
}

summary(mod)
```

It should be noted that the [source code for summary.dynlm](https://github.com/cran/dynlm/blob/master/R/dynlm.R#L254) uses the same principle to dispatch to `summary.lm` as part of its output.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This definitely works. I noticed that in the source code a ~summary.newclass is created. Is that recommended for summary outputs?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking but if you are using this in your own packages, I would plan to export the summary.newclass function to the package namespace and provide roxygen documentation for your method just as you would for any other exported function.

Comment: So, I have been using GitHub and editing directly on the site as opposed to roxygen (which I tried once and got nowhere). https://github.com/efriedland/friedland. You are suggesting I create new .R and .Rd files for each of the methods I make?

Comment: How you choose to structure the R folder of your repository (e.g. one function/method per file, grouped by purpose, etc.) doesn't matter much as long as you know where each method lives. I would start cloning your repository and working locally so you can use devtools::document() to generate the documentation for you. Hadley's guide for basic documentation is very helpful https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help and info~ Cheers